# Use Entra External ID or Azure B2C with DataVerse

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, powerapps, dataverse, microsoft-entra-id, microsoft-entra-external-id

Power platform has a great low code tools for fast delivery, including dataverse (aka xrm solutions).
Has anyone managed how to provide solutions based on dataverse to external users which are based on Google Apps tenants?
There are some documents and/or videos about integrating power pages (aka portals) with Azure B2C, which can be valid for Entra External ID, but we are looking to integrate different power platform product (dataverse). As auth on dataverse is based on OAuth, it should be possible to register an dataverse environment url as an Web App on Entra App Registrations.

Got some steps described
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Be1-8lBIeaI
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tQFGMH7RrMI

But none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

At this moment this is not possible. I dived into the topic and doe DataVerse I found out that for now you can only use it with standard MS Entra ID tenant.
You can read more here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/authenticate-oauth

Generally speaking, documentation says:

*If your app is a client that allows the authenticated user to perform operations, you must configure the application to have the Access Dynamics 365 as organization users delegated permission.*

In case of Azure AD B2C or MS Entra External ID for Customers, there is no such connection.
There is "api.crm.dynamics.com" API resources used but it is only accessible through the standard MS Entra ID tenant.